# How to keep additional url params with current page in backbone paginated collection?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, collections, fetch

How to keep latest search params eg: `lat` and `lng` or `additional` and fetch them with current page param when pagination is changed? For now when page is changed other parameters are gone.

Fetch collection with new data params in some View:

```
@options.posts.fetch({ 
  data: { page: 1, lat: x.latitude, lng: y.longitude, additional: eg.test }
  processData: true 
})
```

Paginated Collection:

```
define [
  'backbone'
  'myapp'
  'models/post'
  # 'collections/paginated'
],
( Backbone, App, Post) ->
  class App.Collections.Posts extends Backbone.Collection
    model: Post
    url: "/posts"
    initialize: ->

    fetch: (options = {}) ->
      @trigger "fetching"
      self = this
      success = options.success
      options.success = (resp) ->
        self.trigger "fetched"
        success self, resp if success
      Backbone.Collection::fetch.call this, options

    parse: (resp) ->
      @current_page = resp.current_page
      @total_pages = resp.total_pages
      resp.items
```

**EDIT:**

As you suggested in answer I stored variables in collection and override url function:

```
url: ->
  "/posts?" + $.param(
    additional: @additional
    lat: @lat
    lng: @lng
  )
```

Or in View:

```
@options.posts.url = "/posts?" + $.param({ additional: eg.test, lat: x.latitude, lng: y.longitude })
@options.posts.fetch({reset: true})
```

I don't know whether this pattern is correct but this solution is working.

Comment: You can create custom fields in the collection and store them there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 ways:

1. when server side received fetch request. It pigback the `lat`, `lng` and `additional` values in response.
2. use some structure to store your variables. e.g

   ```
   # use collection object
   @options.posts.lat = x.latitude
   @options.posts.lng = y.longitude
   @options.posts.additional = eg.test

   # use DOM
   $(document).data("lat", x.latitue)
   $(document).data("lng", y.longitude)
   $(docuemnt).data("additional", eg.test)
   ```